# Lubuntu 12.10 asks for super user before prompting for wifi password

Tags: wireless, sudo

I have installed Lubuntu 12.10 on an HP Mini netbook, which required the bcwm source package for wifi to work. (Somehow standard ubuntu didn't need it but it was too resource hungry for the netbook.)

Everything is working fine but as soon as i try to connect to a new wifi network, i am asked for the `root` password, as in a `gksu` prompt.

I am fine with that, but the final user of the netbook isn't quite happy with it. Any ideas on how to make it ask for the wifi password only?

Comment: Well this may be the issue because the `bcwm package` that you are using may be is `owned` by `root`. So whenever you try to invoke it, it asks for the root user privileges. You can try to changing the owner to standard user rather than the root user. May that work & help